# Trouble with MVC3 Routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am stuck on trying to create another route in Global.asax.

I am creating dynamic pages for my website using MVC3.  When I type this URL
/Home/GetPages/About%20Us

It pulls the correct Controller Method and pulls the data.

However, I am trying to modify it to this
/About%20Us

Below is the route I added to the Global file:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Pages", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{PageName}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPages", PageName = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close; all you need to do is remove the default entry for `PageName` and change the URL template to remove the controller and action identifiers.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Pages", // Route name
    "{PageName}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPages" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Also, make sure this route is mapped **after** your other routes, otherwise it'll prevent them from working (because just about any URL except for the root will trigger this route).

Comment: here are my total routes.

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Pages", // Route name
                "{PageName}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPages" } // Parameter defaults
            );

However after trying localhost/About%20Us I still get a 404 error.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I actually reversed the routes and that worked.  Most of the pages are going to be dynamic on the root so this should work fine.  Thank you for the help...